# Function that takes data structure and returns integer

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have received the following code challenge and I am not sure as to what to do. As a front-end developer, I have not used data structures up to this point as well. Any solutions or help would be greatly appreciated. Attached below is the whole challenge.

```
const data = [
  { max: 5, min: -23, code: 'ATGCAGTG', epoch: '1465992000000' },
  { max: 66, min: 33, code: 'CGCCCCGG', epoch: '1466078400000' },
  { max: 93, min: 26, code: 'AGCGCATT', epoch: '1466164800000' },
  { max: 56, min: 44, code: 'CCAGCTCG', epoch: '1466251200000' },
  { max: 29, min: 19, code: 'GCTGTAGT', epoch: '1466337600000' },
  { max: 21, min: -66, code: 'TGGTGATT', epoch: '1466424000000' },
  { max: 91, min: 76, code: 'TCACAGCA', epoch: '1466510400000' },
  { max: 86, min: -14, code: 'TAGAGCCT', epoch: null },
  { max: 63, min: 23, code: 'TTCTCCCG', epoch: '1466683200000' },
];
```

> INSTRUCTIONS
> Write a function (which may use other functions) that takes the above data structure as input and returns an integer which is the largest difference between max and min, where  code starts with the character
> 'T' or 'C' and contains the sequence 'AG', and epoch represents a weekday.
>
> - The fields max and min will be positive or negative integers, code and epoch will always be a string.
> - The field epoch may be null.
> - You may use javascript Date and Math functions. Please avoid using external libraries. Please code in javascript.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: epoch can either be a weekday or null? but not the weekend? is that correct understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if i understood correctly, the epoch may be null, but it cannot be Saturday or Sunday. If this is the case, this would be a possible solution

```
const findMax = (data) => {
 const result = data.filter(element => {
    const isWeekDay = new Date(+element.epoch)
    if(isWeekDay.toString().includes("Sat") || isWeekDay.toString().includes("Sun")){
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}).filter(element => {
    if(element.code.slice(0,1) == "T" || element.code.slice(0,1) == "C"){
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}).filter(element=> element.code.includes("AG")).map(element=> {
    element.difference = element.max - element.min
    return element
}).reduce((prev, curr) => {
      return Math.max(prev.difference, curr.difference)
})
 return result
}

console.log(findMax(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, the epoch bit is not clear. Other than that, assuming, no null epochs, it should be something like below. You'll have to play with the epoch filter.

```
const data = [
  { max: 5, min: -23, code: 'ATGCAGTG', epoch: '1465992000000' },
  { max: 66, min: 33, code: 'CGCCCCGG', epoch: '1466078400000' },
  { max: 93, min: 26, code: 'AGCGCATT', epoch: '1466164800000' },
  { max: 56, min: 44, code: 'CCAGCTCG', epoch: '1466251200000' },
  { max: 29, min: 19, code: 'GCTGTAGT', epoch: '1466337600000' },
  { max: 21, min: -66, code: 'TGGTGATT', epoch: '1466424000000' },
  { max: 91, min: 76, code: 'TCACAGCA', epoch: '1466510400000' },
  { max: 86, min: -14, code: 'TAGAGCCT', epoch: null },
  { max: 63, min: 23, code: 'TTCTCCCG', epoch: '1466683200000' },
];
const findCode = (data) => {
  const codes = data.filter(item => item.code.startsWith('T') || item.code.startsWith('C'));
  const filteredCodes = codes.filter(item => item.code.includes('AG'));
  const filteredEpochs = filteredCodes.filter(item => item.epoch);
  const filteredEpochsWithMaxMin = filteredEpochs.map(item => {
    const maxMin = {
      max: item.max,
      min: item.min,
    };
    return maxMin;
  });
  const maxMinDiff = filteredEpochsWithMaxMin.map(item => item.max - item.min);
  const maxMinDiffMax = Math.max(...maxMinDiff);
  return maxMinDiffMax;
}
console.log(findCode(data));
```